# Can't remove unwanted margins from my code

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm in the process of making a pure CSS gallery, this is what my code looks like at the moment:

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}
#gallery {
  width: 85vh;
  height: 65vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink
}
label > img {
  width: 17vh
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <input id="img1" type="radio" name="img" checked>
  <label for="img1" class="img img1">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img2" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img2" class="img img2">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img3" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img3" class="img img3">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img4" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img4" class="img img4">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img5" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img5" class="img img5">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
```

As you see, there exists a margin even though I set all margins and paddings to 0. Any idea what could be the reason?

Edit: Solved it by applying display: block to the images.

Comment: can use a font-size:0 on the #gallery (because there is spaces between inline elements)

Comment: I don't see margins. I see whitespace. Get rid of all whitespace (line returns, tabs, spaces).

Comment: Also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: @hacketo I didn't know there were spaces between inline-block elements, so even though I didn't apply your solution, I came up with mine thanks to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `font-size:0;` As others have pointed out, the space is showing due to whitespace chars. Either **remove them**, or set `font-size:0;` or use `float:left;` with the images.

### Using `float-left`

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}
#gallery {
  width: 85vh;
  height: 65vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}
label > img {
  width: 17vh;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <input id="img1" type="radio" name="img" checked>
  <label for="img1" class="img img1">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img2" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img2" class="img img2">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img3" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img3" class="img img3">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img4" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img4" class="img img4">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img5" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img5" class="img img5">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
```

### Using `font-size:0;`

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}
#gallery {
  width: 85vh;
  height: 65vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
  font-size: 0;
}
label > img {
  width: 17vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <input id="img1" type="radio" name="img" checked>
  <label for="img1" class="img img1">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img2" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img2" class="img img2">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img3" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img3" class="img img3">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img4" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img4" class="img img4">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
  <input id="img5" type="radio" name="img">
  <label for="img5" class="img img5">
    <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I solved it by making the images display as blocks, which made them go on separate lines, then I used float to put them on the same line again, not realizing I didn't need display: block anymore. Thanks for your solution.